# Chess fatigueness and recovery?

Tags: chess-variants, psychology

I have been playing chess for almost two years now and my playing strength revolves around 1000.

Quite often every month or so, i play below par and drop to 900's and never been consistent. I dont play to win, i enjoy playing chess.

What is causing this? Am i playing too much chess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having some fluctuations in rating is quite natural and not something I would be overly concerned. At your rating level blunders are very common, so that games are to some extent not decided by apparent playing strength (=rating) but by a random process and this shows in your rating fluctuations.

However, with your approach (for fun) to chess you should not be worrying about ratings at all and just enjoy playing.

If you do want to improve your chess there are many ways and even a little work will have a large impact on your playing strength at this level. For suggestions on how to improve see [this question and answers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16565/how-to-learn-chess-if-youre-still-a-3-digit-rating-after-a-few-years/16567#16567).

Answer (score 1):

In order to play chess, you have to try to win :)  Otherwise you are denying your opponent a proper game.

If your strength is bouncing between 900 and 1000 (stagnant), then you are not improving.  If you want to improve, then you have to have a plan to move forward, which normally involves study, training, and/or mentoring (in addition to playing).

There are a lot of ways to begin developing as a player.  A big one is to learn end-game mating scenarios.  Others involve start training tactics, studying openings, recording and re-analyzing your games, joining a club, reading chess articles, etc.

You should create a plan for developing your skills (start with learning end games).  Execute your plan and refine it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A rating of 1000 means is a beginner . Great that you enjoy the Royal Game but you must focus more on studying the game and play less . When I say study it means focus more on Master Level games with Annotations and you would learn why was this game played . Look at YouTube videos especially Matojelic , King Crusher and you would definitely learn it more .